# Show SwiftUI Dialog box on top of UIKit View

Tags: swiftui, uikit

Newbie at SwiftUI here. I am trying to show a dialog built in SwiftUI on top of an existing UIKit View. The idea is to be able to see the content of the UIKit view behind the SwiftUI dialog (like the default behaviour of an alert dialog box). But no what I try, I am unable to see the contents of the UIKit view. Is this even achievable?

I want an alert style dialog with background opacity adjusted somehow to see the contents of the UIKit view. Here is my output:
[alert content hides the view behind it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj8UI.png)

Can somebody please point me in the right direction.

Here is my code sample:

The dialog in SwiftUI:

```
struct TestDialog: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
                Text(.init("Some Text"))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Button 1")
                        .padding(10)
                }
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Button 2")
                        .padding(10)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(
              RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                .foregroundColor(.white))
            .padding(40)
        }
    }
}
```

and the method called in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
func showTestDialog() {
        let testView = TestDialog()
        let testchildView = UIHostingController(rootView: testView)
        
        addChild(testchildView)
        let titleBarOffset: CGFloat = 11
        testchildView.view.frame = view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -titleBarOffset)
        view.addSubview(testchildView.view)
        testchildView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

Comment: Did you try setting the background of the `UIHostingController` to `clear`?

Comment: Wow thanks for the tip. That did the job! I set `testchildView.view.backgroundColor = .clear` and it started appearing as expected. I wonder though, is there no way to handle this inside the SwiftUI view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see through the SwiftUI, you need to make sure it's host view has a transparent background:

```
testchildView.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

This must be done at the host view level, since it is the parent/container.